# Advice on how to deal with an elementary "long-to-prove" statement

Tags: inequalities, advice, symbolic-computation

I am not entirely sure if this question totally fits here. If it doesn't, I apologise in advance.

In a paper I've been working on, we have a very elegant result which, when forgetting about the abstract notions and the fancy definitions, with a lot of simplifications reduces to proving some inequalities, such as the following

> For every $1\leq k \leq n-1$, the following holds:
> $$\frac{n(n-k+2)}{2k(\max(k,n-k)+1)} +
>  (n-k)\left(1-\frac{1}{n-\frac{k}{2}-1}\right) \leq
>  \frac{k(n-2)(n-k)}{(k-1)(n-1)}.$$

My issues are:

1. The above inequality is not trivial (in some sense it is pretty
   tight). So saying "this can be done" and not actually doing it sounds like cheating.
2. With a computer one can see that it holds for all small cases (say
   when the numbers are less than $500$), and that as you increase them
   the difference between the right-hand-side and the left-hand-side
   also increases, so it will "for sure be true" (?)
3. Working out a proof by hand can take several hours, and a full proof might take more than a page long. Including it into a paper would possibly "ruin" the flow of ideas.

Also, I suspect that some software for "proving" such inequalities must exist. I would appreciate a general comment/advice on what to do in a situation like this one.

Comment: Have you considered including the proof in an appendix? That's a not too uncommon solution.

Comment: Well, actually everything is already happening in the appendix :(. I have the main Theorem in Section 3. Its proof is contained in the Appendix A, as it involves lengthy inequalities with sums of binomial coefficients. However, these proofs, after some "clever" (but long) manipulations that allow one to get rid of the sums, reduce to three inequalities as the one I wrote in the post.

Comment: If it's already in the appendices I don't see the issue as most people will just skim read these anyway, am I missing something?

Comment: A "page long proof" sounds like a fantastically short proof for me. If, in addition, it is in the appendix, there does not seem to be anything to worry about.

Comment: There's a chance Fedja comes along and gives a 3-line proof.

Comment: If $k=1$ then what about the $(k-1)$ in the denominator?